# Data frame to barplot

Tags: r

I have reviewed the posted questions/responses re: data frame to barplots but haven't been able to adapt the answers to my problem.  I have a simple table of particle size data that I want to create a barplot from (x = particle size fractions, y = percent composition

I am able to `read.csv` and view my data in R

```
    str(MR_PS)
   'data.frame':    5 obs. of  2 variables:
    $ Particle.Size.Fraction: Factor w/ 5 levels "Clay","Coarse.Sand",..: 4 2 3 5 1
    $ Percent               : int  15 22 28 20 5

    Particle.Size.Fraction Percent
   1                 Gravel      15
   2            Coarse.Sand      22
   3              Fine.Sand      28
   4                   Silt      20
   5                   Clay       5
```

I have read `?barplot` and haven't resolved the issue.

Comment: may be `barplot(setNames(MR_PS[,2], MR_PS[,1]), ylim=c(0,40))`

Comment: That's not an issue... if you read carefully [the documentation for `barplot`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html), you'll see what you need; at the very least: `barplot(height, names.arg)` where `height` is a vector of numbers with the height of the bars and `names.arg` is a vector of names. See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you only need a `barplot` where the bar height is defined by the `Percent` variable and each bar is labeled with the value of the `Particle.Size.Fraction` variable. If I'm correct, this is your solution:

```
# The data frame with your data
df <- data.frame(
  Particle.Size.Fraction = as.factor(c('Gravel','Coarse.Sand','Fine.Sand','Silt','Clay'))
  , Percent = c(15,22,28,20,5)
)
# The bar plot. Add any additional graphical parameters (las, col, cex) you want
barplot(df$Percent, names=df$Particle.Size.Fraction)
```

---

References:

- [R help: `barplot`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html)
- [The Quick-R tutorial: Bar plots](http://statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html)

---

**Tip:** You said in your question that you've *"searched the posted questions/responses" regarding your particular problem, but StackOverflow is not the only source of information. Quoting from [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com) (which, by the way, I recommend everybody to read):

> Try searching the web. This is glib advice, I know, but stay with me. If you’re having trouble getting a decent result, you need to narrow things down. Don’t search for “if statement” if you’re just interested in an if-statement in ruby; instead, try “ruby if statement”. What might be even better is finding a site that’s specific to the language or technology you’re working with, and searching there. [...] Someone else has probably asked your question - or maybe a hundred someones.

R help is not the only source of information regarding R, nor SO. The [Quick-R tutorial](http://statmethods.net) is another good one. Google around a bit and you'll find hundreds of sites with info about R, not only references, but also tutorials.